# Codeigniter and database issues

Tags: php, codeigniter

Right im new to this and a little out of my depth. Ok so I'm trying to bring in some data and im getting some errors and am I a little confused as to whats going on.

here is the model code:

```
 public function get_webstore_sets($limit, $offset) {
        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from('st_posts');
        $this->db->where("type", "webstore");
        $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
        $this->db->order_by('created', 'DESC');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $data = $query->result_array();
        return$data;
    }

    public function count_webstore_sets() {
        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from('st_posts');
        $this->db->where("type", "webstore");
        $this->db->order_by('created', 'DESC');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $count = $query->num_rows();
        return $count;
    }
```

and here is what im trying in the controller:

```
class Webstore extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model("post");
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper("url");


    }
    public function index() {

        $this->data['posts'] = $this->post->get_webstore_sets($limit=null, $offset=null); // calling Post model method getPosts()
        $data = array('page_title' => 'Store', 'video_content');       
        $this->layout("pages/webstore", $data);
    }


}
```

and then bringing it in on HTML:

```
 <?php foreach ($posts as $webstore): ?>


            <div class="col-md-12" style="height: 225px;">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <?php
                    $webstore['images'] = explode(".", $webstore['images']);
                    ?>
                    <img class="thumbnail" width="250px" src="<?php echo $video['images'][1]; ?>.gif"/>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <h3><?php echo $webstore['title']; ?></h3>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                    Date Added: <?php echo date('d-m-y', strtotime($webstore['created'])) ?>
                     <hr>
                     <a href="http://clips4sale.com/64171/10768027" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary center-block">Select or Exclusive to www.Borderlandbound.com<br> Please Visit Our Clips Store For <br>Many More Ultra-Hot Videos Like This</a>
<hr>
                </div>

            </div>

            <hr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I know the connection is ok as the site is bringing in data from else where.

and this is the error im getting :

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: posts

Filename: pages/webstore.php

Line Number: 39

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: pages/webstore.php

Line Number: 39
```

I have blanked out the file path just in case ;) Edited for the above errors

Comment: Not related to your problem but I see that you have this code `$this->load->model("post");` in both the constructor and the `index()` method of `class Webstore`.  You only need it once. If you have other methods that use that model leave it in the constructor.

Comment: yeah removed it from the index now thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In this code:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->data['posts'] = $this->post->get_webstore_sets($limit=null, $offset=null); // calling Post model method getPosts()
    $data = array('page_title' => 'Store', 'video_content');       
    $this->layout("pages/webstore", $data);
}
```

you are passing `$data` array to view, but not `$this->data` one. Also, `'video_content'` element of `$data` array should have it's key to let you to approach to it in view. Or it is key itself missing value?

Change it to:

```
public function index() {

    $this->data['posts'] = $this->post->get_webstore_sets($limit=null, $offset=null); // calling Post model method getPosts()
    $this->data['page_title'] = 'Store';
    $this->layout("pages/webstore", $this->data);
}
```

Now, you should be able to get `$posts` variable in view file. Just check what you have to do with value/key 'video_content'.

Comment: Awesome thank you, just need to work out why its showing a blank screen and then it should all be done , but have a feeling thats something to do with the HTML, thanks for all your help

Comment: SHould this line  $this->db->where("type", "webstore"); pick the column type and the type value webstore??

Comment: Check if you are getting any valid results from DB. At the end of model's method put `var_dump($data);exit;` That way you will stop further executing at the point and see if query is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `get_webstore_sets()` without a parameter, so either fill in some parameters (limit, offset) or define the function as follows:

```
public function get_webstore_sets($limit=null, $offset=null) ...
```

I would suggest giving the parameter though in the function `index()` of class `Webstore`.

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: webstore

Filename: pages/webstore.php

Line Number: 39

Comment: This means you are attempting to use a variable (named 'webstore') that has no value assigned to it.

Comment: ok cool , where do I assign the value? Sorry I'm a noob whose php dev has let him down! I really appreciate all the help

Comment: You will have to edit your question and show the code that uses $webstore.